# How to use .format in a Bazel $(location ....)

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to get locations from a bazel target which is containing a format string.

In the cmd section of the genrule I'd like to put a list of files which are found in the target `//project/test{}.format(templateName)` which resolves to `//project/test:fileList`.
When I use `"$(locations//project/test:fileList)`, everything works completely fine. However, I do not know the full target name, as the last part will be passed via the `templateName` variable.
Thus, I have to assemble the full target name using `'//project/test:{}'.format(templateName)`.

For me, it looks a bit like the`templateName` variable could not be resolved as it is already inside a string.

The Error which is thrown: `invalid label in $(locations) expression: invalid package name '"//project/test': package names may not contain '//' path separators`

Can you tell me how to use `$(locations ....)` together with `.format(...)`?

```
def test_genrule(templateName):
    native.genrule(
        name = "example",
        src = "//project/test:{}.format(templateName),
        outs = result,
        cmd = ["$(execpath //project/tools:tool)"] +
               "$(locations '//project/test:{}'.format(templateName))"

        tools = ["//project/tools:tool"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.format` interpolation is a Starlark concept and the location expansion of `cmd` doesn't know anything about it. Therefore, the `.format` call has to happen outside the strings of the `cmd` list.

```
def test_genrule(templateName):
    native.genrule(
        name = "example",
        src = "//project/test:{}.format(templateName),
        outs = result,
        cmd = ["$(execpath //project/tools:tool)",
               "$(locations //project/test:{})".format(templateName)],

        tools = ["//project/tools:tool"]
```

Comment: Sometimes the solution is so easy and clear, that you can't see it. Works like charm. Thanks!